# Dockerfile RUN command not working

Tags: command, websphere, dockerfile

I am trying to create [`IBM WAS`](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/appserv-was) image from my local binary but it is not working . i used the dockerfile and added below command but getting error :

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum update -y
RUN "/docker/software/im/installc -acceptLicense -accessRights nonAdmin \
-installationDirectory /docker/IBM/InstallationManager -dataLocation /docker/var/ibm/InstallationManager -showProgress"
```

**Error:**

> ---> Running in 206e970b75c8 /bin/sh: /docker/software/im/installc -acceptLicense -accessRights nonAdmin -installationDirectory /docker/IBM/InstallationManager -dataLocation
>   /docker/var/ibm/InstallationManager -showProgress: No such file or
>   directory The command '/bin/sh -c "/docker/software/im/installc
>   -acceptLicense -accessRights nonAdmin -installationDirectory /docker/IBM/InstallationManager -dataLocation
>   /docker/var/ibm/InstallationManager -showProgress"' returned a
>   non-zero code: 127

Answer (score 0):

Docker is trying to run `installc` from within the image. The image centos:centos6 image does not contain IBM Installation Manager.

I recommend taking a look at the [WebSphere traditional Docker images published by IBM to Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/). If you wish to create something slightly different for example use centos instead of ubuntu then take a look at the [instructions for building WebSphere traditional Docker images](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional), they are Apache licensed so you are free to adapt them.

Comment: thanks for responding . I  am trying to install IBM Websphere with license version . so docker hub will not help me . So i  followed IBM docker file from github but still i am getting error. it is strange to me .

Answer (score 0):

Docker build error : 
/bin/sh: /tmp/im/installc: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c unzip -qd /tmp/im /tmp/agent.installer.linux.gtk.x86_1.8.0.20140902_1503.zip &&  /tmp/im/installc    -acceptLicense    -show            Progress    -installationDirectory /usr/lib/im    -dataLocation /var/im &&  rm -rf /tmp/agent.installer.linux.gtk.x86_1.8.0.20140902_1503.zip /tmp/i            m' returned a non-zero code: 126

Linux version : AWS linux  3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 20 02:37:52 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux